# Secure Database Connection from decompilation inspection

Tags: .net, obfuscation, decompiling, decompiler

I've currently got a project that I worked on for some friends to play around with; but my database connection is exposed in the raw client.  So the username and password connection strings are exposed; what would be a solid solution to encrypt that string?

A service that will encrypt the transport layer?
Encrypt the database connection string?
Abstract the connection string?
Or any other form that can help me secure the data inquiries.

My original thought was to use an anti-decompiler; but that still wouldn't hide or secure the database connection string.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Dotfuscator Community Edition comes free with purchased versions of Visual Studio (well, free insofar as the money you spent on VS)

Comment: The sql connection string should not be part of the client in the first place. You don't need an obfuscator, you need an improved architecture.

Comment: If you _do_ decide to purchase a protection tool down the road, I would recommend http://www.codewall.net - I did a lot of research in this space, and found it to be the most solid implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have the application talking directly to the SQL server. Have it talking to a web-facing API that can talk to the SQL server and your application talking to the API. .Net Web Services / WCF make this really easy .

Answer (score 1):

What sense is there in obfuscating code ? A connection to a database server is a network connection. That can be seen on network level whether you obfuscate your code or not.

Obfuscating code usually is a bad idea. The typical motivation is that the authors are ashamed of their implementation.

Apart from that: what is the problem with your connection to the database server not being "hidden" (though that is not possible anyway) ? Hiding a few details never really makes things secure. If you are concerned about authentication credentials getting visible, then encrypt your database connection.

Comment: because the connection is plain as day.... it literally reads...

DataSource=ftpinfo.com;Username:username;Password:thepassword;

Why would i NOT want to hide this?..... also if i encrypt the database connection itself, the encryption method can still be found in the code.

Comment: @MattHam Obfuscating your script won't change that. You have to use an encrypted connection. Knowledge about the encryption method is no security thread (provided it is a reasonable encryption). Amateurish attempts to hide things IS a security thread. But it's your decision.

Comment: Ok feel free to point into the right direction about encrypting the connection in a reasonable way.

Comment: @MattHam The choices obviously depend on the client you use, the algorithms the server supports and your operating system. That should be documented. If you can't get that to work you can also think about using an ssl tunnel to protect your otherwise unencrypted connection.

Comment: SQL Server 2008, VS 2008- VB.Net, Operating system? for what? the server? Windows server 2008, locally windows 7

Comment: @arkascha, I would like to point out that the generalized statement "obfuscating code usually is a bad idea" is pure opinion. There are many reasons to obfuscate/encrypt - including providing at least SOME resistance to the curious-Joe with a copy of Reflector. While many developers only write code that 'gets the job done', others actually have some unique IP in their algorithms they want to attempt to protect. If we always walked the path of 'it doesn't provide 100% coverage, so we will just forgo any coverage' - then we would never take any due diligence.

Comment: @Adam What I was trying to point out is that obfuscation gives you a wrong sense of security. If your code and the base you build on is sound and solid there is no reason to obfuscate it. Then it does its job and anyone can (and should) see what it is doing. There is no security thread in that. You only have a problem when your code or base has security holes easy to exploit. I say: fix those holes instead and you have that security you want. What worth does this "IP" have so many "genuine" coders always rant about, if all it takes to break things is taking a quick glimpse at the source?

Comment: @arkascha, Seems youre talking about the exploitation of flaws. Sure, in that case, the best security is to have no vulnerabilities. However, Im taking about obscuring a complex program to make trade secrets difficult to decipher. Reverse engineering for theft comes down to cost/benefit - cost of reverse-engineering, vs the cost of RE-engineering. If you do nothing to obscure your intellectual-property, you make theft financially viable. Obfuscation can make complex code EXTREMELY difficult to understand. Especially when the application domain is not one of comp-sci (i.e. legal, medical, etc)

Comment: @Adam This is the most common mistake in software technology: the idea that there is an intellectual property that you can only protect by keeping things secret, distrusting your customers and making usage of your technology as hard as you can. The OP wants to obfuscate because the only protection against missusage is apparently a password. A password he stores on a customers system: LOL. All I said is: fix the original problem. Use a solution that does not have that huge security problem, then you don't have to obfuscate. Those solutions are secure, easy to use and attract customers.